Can you explicitly assign a generic function type to a const definition?
Let's say we have the following:
type Foo<T> = { bar: T };

type MyFunc<T> = (val: T) => Foo<T>;

const testFunc = <T>(val: T): Foo<T> => {
   const result: Foo<T> = { bar: val };
   return result;
}; 

As you can see, testFunc implements the function type described by MyFunc; however, if the MyFunc type is described elsewhere then you wouldn't know that. Never mind the why, but how can I make this explicit?
I can't do the following because Typescript will flag the T in MyFunc as an error:
const testFunc : MyFunc<T> = <T>(val: T): Foo<T> => {
   const result: Foo<T> = { bar: val };
   return result;
}; 


Is this possible?

• Please [edit] your code so it's a [mre] without errors unrelated to your question. Your testFunc is syntactically invalid. Try it in an IDE and make the requisite fix so it's not distracting. • MyFunc isn't generic function type.  Or rather, it's a generic {function type} but it's not a {generic function} type. You want type MyFuncGen = <T>(val: T) => Foo<T> instead. The two types are related but TS can't express the relationship in the type system. See this question and its answer. Does that fully address the q? Or am I missing something?

@jcalz Thank you, that does indeed answer the question!

@jcalz If you don't mind me asking, where did you get such a deep understanding of typescript? Any resources you'd recommend?

Honestly, at this point it's years of following their release notes and GitHub issues. Unfortunately I don't have a more concise resource to recommend.
